# How to get applied coupon details in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

I need to get applied coupon details in cart **form.phtml**

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart
```

In this path we have shopping cart files are there like **coupon.html, form.html**

In a coupon.html file we have code to get coupon

```
 $block->escapeHtml($block->getCouponCode())
```

How to get this coupon detail in other **phtml** file **form.phtml**

Comment: Provide detail on this provide the full path of file where & What you want

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Please check my updated question

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add

```
<?php

    $quote = $block->getQuote();
    $couponCode = $quote->getCouponCode();

    // to get discount amount, we need to loop the quote items
    $discountAmount = 0;
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
       if($discount = $item->getDiscountAmount()){
           $discountAmount += $discount;
       }
    }

    // we can also get the discount more simply
    $discountAmount = $quote->getSubtotal() - $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount();

?>
```

to form.phtml.

Form.phtml uses the class \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart for it's $block variable. 
\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\AbstractCart which has a getQuote() method.

With the quote in hand, all that's left is to get the coupon code and whatever other info you need.

Answer (score 1):

*Rakesh Code Provided will Give you **Coupon Code** which you are applied to cart Page what else you required please specify will accordingly on that meanwhile try the:*

```
$couponappiledToCartPage = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon');
print_r($couponappiledToCartPage->getCouponCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define below method inside your form.phtml file,

```
$getCoupon = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon');
echo $getCoupon->getCouponCode();
```

Comment: I need to get coupon amount

Comment: you need to fetch quote object and may be its getDiscountAmount() is worked for your case

Comment: Please explain how to get discount amount in same page

Comment: How to get available coupon code on cart page which is valid